# I can't find how to solve this parse error

Tags: octave

I was writing a Lagrange interpolation algorithm but my code keeps signaling me a parse error about my "endif"

```
function g=lagrange(x,y,a)
  g=0
  n=length(x)
for j = 0:n
  if j~=i
    v=v*((a-x(i))/(x(j)-x(i))
  end
   g=g+v*y(j)
  endfor
endfunction
```

and even if I try with a simple "end", it says

```
  syntax error

>>>   endif
          ^

>> lagrange

parse error near line 7 of file C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\octave\lagrange.m

  syntax error

>>>   end
        ^
```

Comment: Try to keep your brackets balanced! Errors on `end` usually indicate an error on a line above it.

Comment: If you put the cursor after a parenthesis in the Octave editor it will highlight the matching parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
v=v*((a-x(i))/(x(j)-x(i))
```

Has more open parentheses than close parentheses. Fix that and your syntax error should go away.